# Creating django form with null and blank field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form where both fields is optional however, i keep getting an error when setting `null` and `blank`. what am i doing wrong?

**Error**

```
super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfile(forms.Form):
    """
    A form that lets a user change their profile information
    """
        first_name = forms.CharField(
        label=("Fornavn"),
        strip=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label=("Efternavn"),
        strip=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        self.user.first_name = first_name
        self.user.last_name = last_name
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

Comment: You're mixing up model field arguments with form field arguments. You probably want `required=false` (instead of `blank` and `null`) in your form fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @danielcorreia said you don't use `blank` in a form, use `required = False` instead.

```
class EditProfile(forms.Form):
    """
    A form that lets a user change their profile information
    """
        first_name = forms.CharField(
        label=("Fornavn"),
        strip=False,
        required=False
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label=("Efternavn"),
        strip=False,
        required=False
    )
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        self.user.first_name = first_name
        self.user.last_name = last_name
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save it as `None` in case when no data provided in the form for that field. You can do it with `empty_value` parameter to `CharField` ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.empty_value)):

```py
field_name = forms.CharField(required=False, empty_value=None)
```

**Note:** You should save `null` to a char field ONLY if you want to distinguish between `null` and "" (blank) on that field. Otherwise, a nullable char field is not much recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The `CharField` cunstructor dosent take `blank` as an argument. You should use `required = False` instead of using `blank` and `null` fields. By defaylt `required` is `True`. To make your code work write:

`first_name = forms.CharField(label=("Fornavn"), strip=False, required=False)`